# Sparse matrixes for matrix-vector product in PageRank computation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm implementing some iterative algorithms for calculating the PageRank of a webgraph, and I'm having some trouble finding the best way to store in memory some matrixes.

I have a `B` `n x n` matrix, which rappresents the webgraph ( `B[i,j]=1/outdegree[j]` if there's an arc from `j` to `i`, `0` otherwise; `outdegree[j]` is the number of outgoing arcs from node `j`) and which I'm storing as a `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` since of course it has mostly `0` entries. The problem is I have to compute many matrix x vector products of the type `Px`, where

```
P = B + (1/n)*e*d^T
```

where `e` is the all ones vector and `d` is a boolean vector that has `1` in component `j` if `outdegree[j] > 0`. Basically `e*d^T` is sort of a linear algebra "trick" to write a `n x n` matrix with columns either all made of `1`s or `0`s, depending if the corresponding entry in `d` is `1` or `0`.

So I'm struggling with two, not totally independent, things:

1. How do I achieve the same "trick" in numpy, since `e*d.T` simply computes the scalar product, while I want a matrix. I guess it's some clever use of broadcasting and slicing, but I'm still new with numpy and can't figure it out
2. If I simply define `P` as above (supposing I've found a solution to 1.), I loose the memory advantage I gained storing `B` as a sparse matrix, and suddenly I need to store `n^2` floats. And anyways the matrix I'm adding to `B` is very redundant (there are only two types of columns), so there must be a better way than storing the whole matrix in memory. Any suggestions? Keep in mind that it has to be in a way as to easily allow computation of `P.dot(x)`, for `x` an arbitrary vector

Comment: It would help if you could add some code that generates example input variables (B, d, e, etc) in the appropriate shape/type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, as expressions with `np.dot` will be bulky, let `∙` denote matrix multiplication, `e`, `d` and `x` be vectors, i.e have shape (n, 1), and in expression with square brackets `*` is a python's list multiplcation. Then, by associativity

```
(e∙d.T)∙x = e∙(d.T∙x) = [[d.T∙x] * n]
```

where `d.T∙x` is a scalar, and

```
P∙x = B∙x + 1/n * e∙d.T∙x = B∙x + 1/n * [[d.T∙x] * n]
```

so to be able to make your computations, you can store only vector d. Note that `d.T∙x` (or equivalently `np.dot(d.T, x)` if arrays used) is vectors product and is a cheap operation relative to matrix multiplication.

Comment: yeah, I had just figured out essentially the same thing, instead of writing `P.dot(x)` when I need it, I simply write `B.dot(x) + (d.dot(x)*e)/n`. This way I solve problem 2. and entirely avoid problem 1.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to point 1. is:

[`numpy.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)

It creates a `B` (MxN) matrix from a `v1` (M) array and a `v2` (N) array such that `B(i,j) = v1[i]*v2[j]`

The answer to 2. is more complex.

1. If you don't need `B` again, you can simply define it as a `numpy.empty((n,n))`, fill it as in the beginning of the question and then `B += (1/n)*np.outer(e, d)`
2. if `n` is not too big, probably having a sparse or a standard matrix does not make much of a difference
3. If possible consider `np.outer(e, d)` as a sparse matrix and then try some of the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254248/efficiently-accumulating-a-collection-of-sparse-scipy-matrices)